# how to make android transparent keyboard?

Tags: android

I am writing an Android application for API 2.2, where I need to use transparent keyboard and I have a problem. I can't find how to make keys for the keyboard. I can set alpha for key icon by setting this.

```
mQwertyKeyboard.getKeys().get( i ).icon.mutate().setAlpha( 0 );
```

where `mQwertyKeyboard` is `QWERTYKeyboard extends Keyboard`, but how do I set alpha for key background? Thank you for help.